# Why is Seven of Nine called Seven of Nine?

Tags: character, star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I'm pretty sure there's a lot more than nine Borgs, and probably quite a few that have groups of nine entities.

Is there any in-universe description of how *Star Trek: Voyager*'s Seven of Nine gained her name, and how the naming system works for Borg entities?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16490/what-does-seven-and-nine-mean-in-seven-of-nine

Answer (score 15):

That's not her **full** designation, it's a shorthand for her full "Borg Name" which is

> "Seven of Nine, Tertiary Adjunct of Unimatrix 01."

Essentially that equates to **at least** "7-9-03-U01" which is more than adequate as a *unique* identifier.

I'd have to do additional research but it should be noted that these designations *are subject to change*.

I seem to recall there was at least one Borg who changed designation based on the number in his group.

Possibly related [**Q&A on SF&F**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47154/borg-naming-conventions) and [**Do the Borg get promoted?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64410/do-the-borg-get-promoted) and [**What does “Seven” and “Nine” mean in “Seven of Nine”?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16490/what-does-seven-and-nine-mean-in-seven-of-nine/16505#16505)

Comment: Surely there are more than 79301 Borg.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, posting my own answer because I actually found new sources/info! So as Paulie_D mentioned, Seven's full designation (which you can also find on [the Wikipedia page for her character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_of_Nine)) is "Seven of Nine, Tertiary Adjunct of Unimatrix 01." If you go from beginning to end of the designation, you're going from most specific to most general description of her placement within the Borg collective.

In this case, "7 of 9" means that she's the seventh drone in her particular group/unit of 9 drones within the ship she's on, based on info from the [fandom Wiki page](https://borgcollective.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_Drone) on Borg drones. (And group sizes can vary — in *The Next Generation* episode "I, Borg," the drone nicknamed "Hugh" is ["third of five"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hugh) within his unit.)  "Tertiary adjunct" tells you Seven's particular group's place within their unimatrix, which [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unimatrix) defines as a "subdivision ... used to designate groups of Borg drones and regions of space."

Based on the information that we get from *Voyager* about [Unimatrix 01](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unimatrix_01), unimatrixes (unimatrices?) are the broadest/largest subdivisions of drones within the collective. They then get broken down into "adjuncts" and possibly even into smaller units within those adjuncts, hence how you get designations like "Seven of Nine" and "Third of Five" rather than "Seven of X billion and counting."

Comment: "adjunct" isn't even necessarily a breakdown, it could very well be a category. After all, an adjunct is by English definition an add-on supplement to something else. You can't have an "adjunct" without it being an adjunct *to* something. So, a "tertiary adjunct" is "an addition [to something else] of third tier importance or redundancy". Its entirely possible there are "secondary coprocessors", "primary executors", and who knows what else.

Comment: I always read "tertiary adjunct" as being basically "detached officer". An agent of the queen. Which makes sense given her original role was exactly that. A Drone given operational leadership and independence to interact with the Voyager crew on a sensitive mission. It also hints at why retrieving her was a point of interest for the Queen.

Answer (score -6):

Seven of nines name is a subtle in joke of trek franchise's depiction of what some fans call "Rule of Seven" where by cast consist of 7 individuals in main roster with often an undisclosed 8th or more added bonus

- TOS: 1)Kirk 2)Spock 3)McCoy 4)Scott 5)Sulu 6)CHekov 7)Uhura 8)Red shirts and Nurse chapel
- TNG: 1) Picard 2)Riker 3)Tasha/Worf 4)Data 5)Geordi 6)Crusher 7) Troi   8)Wesley 9)Guinan
- DS9: 1)Sisko 2)Kira 3)Dax 4)Bashir 5)O'Brien 6)Odo 7) Worf   8)Nog  9)Qwark/Rom
- VOY: 1)Janeway 2)Chakotay 3)Tuvok 4)B'leana 5)Paris 6)Kim 7) EMH Doctor  8)Neelix/Kes 9) Seven (introduced season 4 when Kes left)

Comment: Could you provide some evidence that a) this fan-made rule exists (I can't find any mention of it on Google) and b) that Seven of Nine's name was an intentional reference to this rule?

Comment: Wouldn't that make her 9 of 9?  LILO, if you're an accountant.